# VideoView Loader Android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have implemented videoview in one of my fragment. It's working fine but there is one problem I am unable to set a loader or progress bar over the videoview. My progressbar is working for the whole screen but I only want it over the videoview so that user can understand that a video is loading.

Below is my java and xml code.Please help me with the solution.

FragmentTwo.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.VideoView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {


    public FragmentTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

     public static VideoView videoview;
    private static ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

          videoview=(VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.video);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


        return view;
    }

     void storeRecievedUrl(String url){
          String VideoURL = url;
        System.out.println(VideoURL);
        // progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Buffering Video...", true);

         try {

             MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(getActivity());
             mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);

             Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
             videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
             videoview.setVideoURI(video);
             videoview.start();
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         videoview.requestFocus();
         videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

             public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                 mp.start();
                 mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                         mediaPlayer.start();
                     }
                 });
             }
         });

    }

}
```

fragment_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </VideoView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is main activity xml on which i am inflating my fragment two.
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_height="350dp">

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/frgten"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please use the following xml to replace your fragment_two.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <VideoView
      android:id="@+id/video"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

  <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using RelativeLayout in fragment_two.xml instead of LinearLayout and put your progressbar on top of videoview.